# Android Picasso - Images not being requested

Tags: android, kotlin, picasso

I have a `RecyclerView` that displays a list of items, each containing an image. That image is being requested from an API and being loaded into the `ImageView` using data binding and Picasso. Here is the `ViewHolder` where I have set up the BindingAdaptor for the data binding:

```
class SearchResultViewHolder(private val binding: SearchResultBinding) :
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
    public fun update(book: GoodreadsBook?, onAdd: () -> Unit) {
        binding.model = SearchResultViewHolderViewModel(book, onAdd);
        binding.executePendingBindings();
    }

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        @BindingAdapter(value = ["imageUrl", "error"], requireAll = false)
        fun setImageUrl(view: View, imageUrl: String?, error: Drawable?) {
            Picasso.with(view.context).load(imageUrl).error(error).into(view as ImageView)
        }
    }

}
```

The update function is a function that I use to bind the data I receive from the `RecyclerView` adapter to the `ViewHolder`, so it's not relevant to the image loading process.

When running the app, nothing gets loaded into the `ImageViews`, neither the actual image, nor the error drawable. Looking with the profiler, I saw that a couple network requests are made, but nothing comes back, not a response, not a timeout, not an error, nothing.

I have internet permissions in the `AndroidManifest`, and I can confirm those are working since the API request for the image urls goes through. With that said the API runs on localhost so there might be some configuration problem (either with the app or with the emulator) that prevents the app from connecting to the Internet.

Any idea what can cause this?

Edit: Here is the adapter for my `RecyclerView`:

```
class SearchResultsListViewAdapter(
    private val viewModel: SearchViewModel,
    private val ctx: Context
) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<SearchResultViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): SearchResultViewHolder {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context);
        val binding = SearchResultBinding.inflate(inflater, parent, false)
        return SearchResultViewHolder(binding);
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return viewModel.getSearchResults().value?.size ?: 0;
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: SearchResultViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.update(viewModel.getSearchResults().value?.get(position)) {
            viewModel.addToReadingList(ctx, viewModel.getSearchResults().value?.get(position))
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: which Adapter are you using? ListAdapter, RecyclerView.Adapter? Can you share code for `onCreateViewHolder` and `onBindViewHolder`? I assume that you call update in the `onBindViewHolder`, correct? where exactly do you call `setImageUrl`?

Comment: @Stachu Added the code. I don't call setImageUrl. That method is a BindingAdapter that I use with the DataBinding library. Alos, I checked that the method gets called for every item in the list